Openstreetmap tile server not working to due differing version of apache
I am trying to set up an OpenStreetMap tile server, but the server refuses to install apache2 due to an existing version within cpanel which prevents the renderer from working.
It looks like it also installs libapache2-mod-tile which works in concert with apache2, but is there any way to get it working with my version of Apache "Apache/2.4.59 (cPanel)"
Everything is complete up to testing the /hot/0/0/0.png link, which just 404s rather than showing the world map. I've installed the Azerbaijan data as per their sample.
I'm working from instructions here: https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-ubuntu-24-04-lts/

Not related to software programming. Maybe consider asking at https://community.openstreetmap.org/.
